# Generic DAO and Wrapper

Tags: hibernate, dao

In order to finish a uni project I need to create a generic DAO.

I followed the generic DAO design as found in the Manning's book Java persistence with hibernate. en ended up with the following methods.

```
findById(ID id, boolean lock)
findAll()
findByExample(T example)
makePersistent(T entity)
makeTransient(T entity)
flush()
clear()
```

The problem is that these method are not enough for my project, which consist of searching entities, ordering them and paging them. I understand that I can do that by creating a method like

```
List<T> find(DetachedCriteria dc)
```

The problem is that would mean that I expose an hibernate interface to the business layer and I don't want that.

I want to create an interface say MyCriteria and a class say MyCriteriaImpl that would do the same as the DetachedCriteria but would let me change the persistence provider by changing just the implementation. I guess it's possible.

The problem is that I don't have time to write such code.

**What I want to know is if there is a pattern that would let me create the MyCriteria interface, and in the MyCriteriaImpl just call methods of the hibernate criteria api.**

Like :

```
MyCriteriaImpl mci = new MyCriteriaImpl();
mci.addRestrictionLike(property, String value);
```

and that would just mean a call to :

```
DetachedCriteria dc = new DetachedCriteria();
dc.add(Restrictions.like(property, value)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this one. It has pagination as well as lucene integration. I created this one for one of my projects. Make sure every DAO extends from it. Take out what you do not need.

```
package com.isavera.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.MultiFieldQueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.search.FullTextSession;
import org.hibernate.search.Search;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;

import com.isavera.actions.utils.Application;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractDAOImpl<E> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements AbstractDAO<E>, ApplicationContextAware {


private static final String CLASS_NAME = AbstractDAOImpl.class.getName();

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);

private static ApplicationContext _applicationContext;

private final Class<? extends E> _entityClass;

/**
 * @param entityClass
 */
public AbstractDAOImpl(Class<? extends E> entityClass) {
    super();

    _entityClass = entityClass;
}


public void delete(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "delete", entity);

    getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "delete");
}

public void evict(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "evict", entity);

    getHibernateTemplate().evict(entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "evict");
}

public void deleteAll(Collection<E> entities) {
    getHibernateTemplate().deleteAll(entities);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findByNamedQuery(String queryName) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery(queryName);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(String queryName, String paramName, Object value) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(queryName, paramName, value);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(String queryName, String[] paramNames, Object[] values) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(queryName, paramNames, values);
}

public E get(Serializable id) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "get", id);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E entity = (E) getHibernateTemplate().get(_entityClass, id);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "get", entity);

    return entity;
}

public List<E> get(Criterion... criterion) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "get", criterion);

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(_entityClass);

    for (Criterion c : criterion) {
        criteria.add(c);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(criteria.list());

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "get", list);

    return list;
}

public boolean isEntityAttached(E entity) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().contains(entity);
}

public E load(Serializable id) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "load", id);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E entity = (E) getHibernateTemplate().load(_entityClass, id);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "load", entity);

    return entity;
}

public E load(Serializable id, LockMode lockMode) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "load", new Object[] { id, lockMode });

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E entity = (E) getHibernateTemplate().load(_entityClass, id, lockMode);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "load", entity);

    return entity;
}

public void load(E entity, Serializable id) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "load", new Object[] { entity, id });

    getHibernateTemplate().load(entity, id);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "load");
}

public void lock(E entity, LockMode lockMode) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "lock", new Object[] { entity, lockMode });

    getHibernateTemplate().lock(entity, lockMode);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "lock");
}



public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection<E> entities) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(entities);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E merge(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "merge", entity);

    E persistentEntity = (E) getHibernateTemplate().merge(entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "merge", persistentEntity);

    return persistentEntity;
}

public void refresh(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "refresh", entity);

    getHibernateTemplate().refresh(entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "refresh");
}

public Long save(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "save", entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "save");

    return (Long) getHibernateTemplate().save(entity);
}

public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "saveOrUpdate", entity);

    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "saveOrUpdate");
}

public void update(E entity) {
    LOG.entering(CLASS_NAME, "update", entity);

    getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);

    LOG.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "update");
}

/**
 * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
 */
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    setStaticApplicationContext(applicationContext);
}

private static void setStaticApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    _applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

/**
 * @param queryName
 * @return count
 */
protected int getCounter(String queryName) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Number> counterList = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery(queryName);

    return counterList == null || counterList.isEmpty() ? 0 : counterList.iterator().next().intValue();
}

/**
 * @param queryName
 * @param paramName
 * @param value
 * @return count
 */
protected int getCounter(String queryName, String paramName, Object value) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Number> counterList = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(queryName, paramName, value);

    return counterList == null || counterList.isEmpty() ? 0 : counterList.iterator().next().intValue();
}

/**
 * @param queryName
 * @param paramNames
 * @param values
 * @return count
 */
protected int getCounter(String queryName, String[] paramNames, Object[] values) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Number> counterList = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(queryName, paramNames, values);

    return counterList == null || counterList.isEmpty() ? 0 : counterList.iterator().next().intValue();
}

public List<E> narrowSearch(String keyword) {
    List<E> result = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(keyword)) {
        return result;
    }
    try {
        Method method = _entityClass.getMethod("SEARCHABLE_FIELDS");
        if (method == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(_entityClass + " should respond to static method call - SEARCHABLE_FIELDS");
        }
        result = narrowSearch(keyword, (String[]) method.invoke(null, null), _entityClass);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public List<E> search(String keyword) {
    List<E> result = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(keyword)) {
        return result;
    }
    try {
        Method method = _entityClass.getMethod("SEARCHABLE_FIELDS");
        if (method == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(_entityClass + " should respond to static method call - SEARCHABLE_FIELDS");
        }
        result = search(keyword, (String[]) method.invoke(null, null), _entityClass);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

private List<E> search(String keyword, String[] fields, Class clazz) {
    Map<String, Integer> paginationOptions = Application.getPaginationOptions();
    Integer pageNumber = Integer.valueOf(1);
    Integer perPage = Integer.valueOf(5);

    if (paginationOptions.containsKey("perPage")) {
        pageNumber = paginationOptions.get("pageNumber");
        perPage = paginationOptions.get("perPage");
    }

    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());

    // create native Lucene query
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, new StandardAnalyzer());
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query;
    try {
        query = parser.parse(keyword);
        // wrap Lucene query in a org.hibernate.Query
        org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, clazz);
        hibQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * perPage);
        hibQuery.setMaxResults(perPage);
        Application.setResultSize(hibQuery.getResultSize());
        // execute search
        return hibQuery.list();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private List<E> narrowSearch(String keyword, String[] fields, Class clazz) {
    /**
     * Need to identify better way of doing this for performance reasons.
     */
    List<E> results = new ArrayList<E>();
    for (String word : keyword.split(" ")) {
        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            results.addAll(search(word, fields, clazz));
        } else {
            results.retainAll(search(word, fields, clazz));
        }
    }
    return results;
}

protected static <T extends AbstractDAO<?>> T getDAO(String beanName, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(_applicationContext.getBean(beanName, clazz));
}


protected int getCount(List<Number> counterList) {
    return counterList == null || counterList.isEmpty() ? 0 : counterList.iterator().next().intValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected List paginateByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(String hqlName, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Query namedQuery = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(hqlName);
    configurePagination(namedQuery);

    for (Entry<String, Object> parameter : params.entrySet()) {
        if (parameter.getValue() instanceof Collection) {
            namedQuery.setParameterList(parameter.getKey(), (Collection) parameter.getValue());
        } else if (parameter.getValue() instanceof Object[]) {
            namedQuery.setParameterList(parameter.getKey(), (Object[]) parameter.getValue());
        } else {
            namedQuery.setParameter(parameter.getKey(), parameter.getValue());
        }

    }
    return namedQuery.list();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected List paginateByNamedQuery(String hqlName) {
    Query namedQuery = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(hqlName);
    configurePagination(namedQuery);

    List result = namedQuery.list();

    resetPagination(namedQuery);

    return result;
}

private void resetPagination(Query namedQuery) {
    getHibernateTemplate().setMaxResults(0);
}

private void configurePagination(Query namedQuery) {
    Integer pageNumber = Application.getPaginationOptions().get("pageNumber");
    Integer perPage = Application.getPaginationOptions().get("perPage");

    if (pageNumber != null && pageNumber > 1) {
        namedQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * perPage);
    }
    namedQuery.setMaxResults(perPage == null ? 5 : perPage);
}



}
```

Comment: Hi, in this class you are exposing this method public List<E> get(Criterion... criterion) which expose the hibernate API to the client, this is the problem I have been trying to solve. Also I prefer to use the Criteria API over the HQL (never really liked it).

Comment: Criteria API is slower I believe than HQL. So try using that.

Answer (score 0):

[Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades) provides all you require in a generic DAO interface. If you can replace your home grown stuff with that or you can browse through its code if you are just looking for reference. It has support for paging etc.

Comment: Hi, It's not really about using a generic dao (I already found hibernate-generic-dao  which have all the ring and whistles I could have wanted). It's more about using the right pattern when you need a solution for a defined problem. That's why I wanted a pattern that let me use the DetachedCriteria class but by instancing an object that is not from hibernate api.